# Privileged instructions in Intel x86-64

Tags: x86-64, instructions, instruction-set

I need to identify the set of all the privileged instructions in x86_64 architecture. I know some of them such as `cli` for clearing interrupts, but when searching in the net for a whole list, I can not find something useful even in the official Intel manuals. Any help, resources, links are welcome.

Comment: @Michael Petch: thank you for the reference. Sometimes, it is not obvious to find the right place. Nonetheless, there are two issues with the previous question (answer): the list is not exhaustive and some instructions are not privileged such as the last one (rdtsc) for monitoring execution time.

Comment: RDTSC can probably considered privileged since the TSD flag in register CR4 being set to 1 can make it a privileged instruction that can only be used in ring 0. I think that should probably be noted in that answer. Which other instructions do you consider privileged that aren't in the list?  `in` and `out` aren't privileged.

Comment: `sti`, `cli` `in` `out`, `popf` are generally not considered privileged since they can be made to run in rings other than 0 if IOPL is set appropriately.

Comment: @Oualid: the first comment on the linked duplicate has your real answer, then, if you're worried that list isn't exhaustive.  Search Intel's volume-2 manual for instructions that say `#GP(0) If the current privilege level is not 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I think I understood: there is no whole list in the manuals for privileged instructions but depending on the context of every instruction. If an instruction induces general protection when executed with CPL <> 0, then it is considered as a privileged instruction.